# Place div in golden ratio: Alternative to absolute position?

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-position, absolute

I have build a page like in this sample below. You can also play around with it on **[codepen](https://codepen.io/SchweizerSchoggi/pen/OJREEdB)**.

The idea was, that the dark grey hero box is placed on the bottom of the viewport. So far so easy.
BUT if the screen is too small in height (e.g. for a small laptop), so that the text would fill most (or even all) of the viewport, the background image could hardly be realized. In this case the hero box should be placed in the golden ratio instead of the bottom of the viewport.

I have already build that solution in the sample as well. Just reduce the height of your browser window.

I just have the feeling that I am doing soemthing wrong in general. At the moment I am placing hero, content and footer in absolute positioned divs. It's working ok as long as there is only static content inside the #content div. But if there is for example an accordion or some other collapsing/dynamic stuff, the position of the footer has to be re-calculated.

I can easily do this in re-calling the ratio function. But meanwhile the whole solution does look wrong or maybe too complex to me.

Isn't there another and more easy solution to place the content div with a RELATIVE position after the hero container?

```js
// call function after everything has been loaded
$(window).load(function() { 
    checkRatio();
});

window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

$(window).resize(function() {
    checkRatio();
});


function checkRatio() {   

    var ratio = 0;
    var contentTopPos = 0;
    var footerTopPos = 0;

    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var headerHeight = $("#hero").height();
    var contentHeight = $("#content").height();

    ratio = (windowHeight / headerHeight);
    contentTopPos = (windowHeight / 1.618);


    if(ratio < 1.618) {
        // Window too small or Content too long
        $("#hero").css('bottom', 'initial');            
        $("#hero").css('top', contentTopPos);            
    } else {
        // Default Position: bottom 0
        $("#hero").css('top', 'initial');
        $("#hero").css('bottom', 0);        
    }


    var sumHeight  = $("#hero").offset().top + $("#hero").height();
    $("#content").css('top', sumHeight + "px");   

    footerTopPos = (sumHeight + contentHeight);
    $("#footer").css('top', footerTopPos + "px");
}
```

```css
body {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
#header_img { 
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     height: 100vh;
     width: 100%;
     background-size: cover;
     z-index: 1;
 }

 #hero_container {
     position: relative;
     height: 100vh;
     width: 100%;
 }
 #hero {
     position: absolute;
     margin: 0 5%;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 90%;
     height: auto;
     background-color: #333;
     box-shadow: 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
     z-index: 2;
 }

 #hero_text {
     padding: 20px;
     color: #fff;
 }

 #content {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: transparent;
     z-index: 3;
 }

 section {
     background-color: #dedede;
     padding: 20px;
     border-bottom: solid 1px #333;
 }

 #footer {
     position: absolute;      
     width: 100%;      
     z-index: 3;
     background-color: #999;
     color: #555;
 }
 #footer_text {
     padding: 10px 20px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header_img" style="background: #ffffff url('https://cdn4.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/80/28/free-sample-rubber-stamp-vector-13448028.jpg') no-repeat center top; background-size: cover;"></div>


<div id="hero_container">
    <div id="hero">
        <div id="hero_text">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
            <h4>Cras felis leo, pellentesque non dui ut, molestie mollis lorem.</h4>
            <p>Fusce venenatis metus id est venenatis ornare. Aliquam id ante et nulla rutrum malesuada vel sit amet felis. Maecenas maximus, quam vitae cursus ultrices, est augue consequat magna, vitae bibendum ex urna eget lacus. Donec quis sagittis diam.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="content">
    <section>
        <h2>Vivamus molestie</h2>
        <p>Sem sit amet posuere elementum, ligula dolor laoreet eros, sed ultrices mi lacus quis est. Sed ut venenatis metus, id consectetur mauris.</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>Mauris sollicitudin ante est</h2>
        <p>Ut ultrices neque volutpat quis. Aenean bibendum dui sed pulvinar vestibulum. Vestibulum finibus ornare dui at lobortis.</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>Sed consequat euismod sem</h2>
        <p>In venenatis lacus luctus in. Nam elementum dolor a magna eleifend consectetur. Curabitur efficitur magna erat, et eleifend enim placerat sit amet. Fusce cursus, sem vel porta tempor, diam dolor auctor lorem, eu venenatis velit lorem ac lectus.</p>
    </section>
</div>


<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_text">&copy; 2020 SchweizerSchoggi</div>        
</div>
```

Comment: In short, would you want the hero div always at the bottom unless the screen height is less than a certain size in which it shouldn't be at the bottom?

Comment: That's exactly what I need to achieve. Or let's say: it's done. But the absolute position of the below content and footer is causing some headaches...

Comment: ...that's why I would love to find another solution

Comment: I will explain my answer in a moment, can you just tell me if it produces your required outcome? View the code snippet in full screen and not full screen to see the differences.

Comment: Morning @koder613 ! Well yeah, this is pretty close to what I would like to achieve. When resizing the window the hero is not always placed on the bottom of the viewport (there sometimes are a few pixels offset) but in general that looks like a really promising idea! Have to check with a real data sample. What I don't understand: why is the height of the hero-container only 98vh ?

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely correct, I should have set it to `100vh`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227020/discussion-between-koder613-and-jonsnow).

Comment: ah, so just a typo - and that was the reason for the offset as well I guess. Hey, that looks pretty awesome now. And if really needed I can set the padding-top for smaller screens by JS calculation as I have done it before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.hero-container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    
}
.hero-content {
    width: 100%;
    background: grey;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

@media only screen and (max-height: 300px) {
  .hero-container{
    padding-top: 25vh;
  }
  .hero-content{
    align-self: flex-start;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-container">
    <div class="hero-content">
         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
            <h4>Cras felis leo, pellentesque non dui ut, molestie mollis lorem.</h4>
            <p>Fusce venenatis metus id est venenatis ornare. Aliquam id ante et nulla rutrum malesuada vel sit amet felis. Maecenas maximus, quam vitae cursus ultrices, est augue consequat magna, vitae bibendum ex urna eget lacus. Donec quis sagittis diam.</p>
        
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <section>
        <h2>Vivamus molestie</h2>
        <p>Sem sit amet posuere elementum, ligula dolor laoreet eros, sed ultrices mi lacus quis est. Sed ut venenatis metus, id consectetur mauris.</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>Mauris sollicitudin ante est</h2>
        <p>Ut ultrices neque volutpat quis. Aenean bibendum dui sed pulvinar vestibulum. Vestibulum finibus ornare dui at lobortis.</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>Sed consequat euismod sem</h2>
        <p>In venenatis lacus luctus in. Nam elementum dolor a magna eleifend consectetur. Curabitur efficitur magna erat, et eleifend enim placerat sit amet. Fusce cursus, sem vel porta tempor, diam dolor auctor lorem, eu venenatis velit lorem ac lectus.</p>
    </section>
    
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_text">&copy; 2020 SchweizerSchoggi</div>        
</div>
```

Comment: as discussed: I just removed the line "align-self: flex-start;" for the smaller screens and it works out very well for me! I am really looking forward using this in a real page next week!